# Check if a textbox control is empty C++ Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox

i have this code that put the value of a textbox field in the variable. The textbox is a Ip Address Control. How can i check if when the user press the OK button the field is empty or not? Thank you

```
char *myVar = new char[16];
*myVar = NULL;

GetDlgItemTextA(hDlg, IDC_MYVAR, myVar, 16);

delete [] myVar;
```

Comment: `*myvar = NULL;` is nonsense, either use `myVar[0] = 0;`, better yet, just use an automatic variable with an initializer, then you don't even need the new and delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to use the `IPM_ISBLANK` message (i am not an expert on winapi, so i may be mistaken).

Comment: +1 This looks like the message behind CIPAddressCtrl::IsBlank

Answer (score 3):

I'd just [get hold of the HWND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645481%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for the control, send it a [WM_GETTEXTLENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632628%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and compare the answer with zero.

Comment: thank you, i'm now using GetWindowTextLength but it returns a false number of character. The textbox is an ip address control and if the user doesn't write anything inside it seems to auto set 0.0.0.0 so i always get 7 characters also if it's empty.

Comment: @Stefano I don't know anything about IP address controls. Are they part of MFC? If it's the MFC control you can just use CIPAddressCtrl::IsBlank (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aae4b2b2%28VS.80%29.aspx). Anyway, you add this modification to your question as an edit to the question rather than a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether `myVar[0]` is zero after calling `GetDlgItemTextA`.

```
char myVar[16];
GetDlgItemTextA(hDlg, IDC_MYVAR, myVar, 16);
if (myVar[0] == 0) // then field is empty
```

Comment: How in the world do you manage a double post on Stack Overflow? (You know you can *edit* your original answer to add a code sample, right? Please don't post a new one. You can also delete one, if that ever becomes necessary.)

Comment: @Cody Gray: It's a mystery to me too! There was some kind of Stack Overflow glitch when I edited the original; perhaps some fail-safe mechanism kicked in. I've deleted the original. +1 for your comment

Answer (score 0):

See here: [GetWindowText Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28VS.85%29.aspx)